# Append Multiple Excel Files(xlsx) together in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, merge, data-science

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob


all_data = pd.DataFrame()
for f in glob.glob("output/test*.xlsx")
    df = pd.read_excel(f)
    all_data = all_data.append(df, ignore_index=True)
```

I want to put multiple xlsx files into one xlsx. the excel files are in the output/test folder. The columns are the same, in all but I want concat the rows. the above code doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let `all_data` be a list.

```
all_data = []
for f in glob.glob("output/test/*.xlsx"):
    all_data.append(pd.read_excel(f))
```

Now, call `pd.concat`:

```
df = pd.concat(all_data, ignore_index=True)
```

Make sure all column names are the same, otherwise this solution won't work.

---

You could also use a `map` version of the `for` loop above:

```
g = map(pd.read_excel, glob.glob("output/test/*.xlsx"))
df = pd.concat(list(g), ignore_index=True)
```

Or the *list comprhension* method as shown in the other answer.

Comment: I want to fetch all the files in the folder 'test'. The test folder has the excel files in it

Comment: @user3821872 use "output/test/*.xlsx". See edit buddy.

Comment: I did do it, works, but I want it to be output in excel file, is there a way to do that? is there a way to see the output of the concat

Comment: @user3821872 Call `df.to_excel('file.xlsx')`. Further questions go in a new question post.

Comment: am guessing this will cause memory issues when we have to run over 2000 files. Is there a way to reduce the memory while loading and writing them ?

Answer (score 6):

Use `list comprehension` + [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
all_data = [pd.read_excel(f) for f in glob.glob("output/test/*.xlsx")]
df = pd.concat(all_data, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: am guessing this will cause memory issues when we have to run over 2000 files. Is there a way to reduce the memory while loading and writing them ?

Comment: @pylearner - simpliest processing first 1000 and then next 1000 files, it depends of your RAM size.

Comment: and then concat both

Comment: So you mean it wont fail for the 1000 files as well ?  If I have very big files in those 1000 files, it may lead to heap memory issues. How do I handle this ?

Comment: @pylearner - how many files not failed?

Comment: 680 ...681 throwed me a memory issue

Comment: @pylearner - so concat each 500 files together and write ouput to files, last concat 4 final files - 0-500, 501-1000, 1001-1500, 1501-2000

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243441/discussion-between-pylearner-and-jezrael).

Comment: can you please reply in the room ?